# Change Image Source Without Reloading Page Using Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, web, server

I am trying to change an image's source dynamically when the user clicks on the element without reloading the page using JavaScript. If I understand correctly, an image's source needs to be assigned a value in relation to Django's static folder, for example

`"{% static 'images\settingsIcon.png' %}";`

However, the {% ... %} expression only seems to get evaluated when the page loads and so the source cannot be found if I change it dynamically with

`myImgElement.src = "{% static 'images\settingsIcon.png' %}";`

Is there a way to dynamically change the image source to a file inside Django's static directory?

Comment: you have to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I am using JavaScript to change the source of the image, however, I am not sure how to assign the source of an image inside the static folder to an element since absolute addresses won't work and the {% static ... %} syntax is only computed when the page loads.

Comment: `{% %}` should generate url to image in static folder when you load page - ie. `var url_to_icon = "{% static 'images\settingsIcon.png' %}";` - so you can later assign to `myImgElement.src = url_to_icon`. Can't you generate all needed urls at start? If you want to generate in JavaScript then you have to do it manually - not with `{% %}`. See what is real path to images in static folder and copy it to JavaScript manually. ie. `myImgElement.src = "/static/folder/images/settingsIcon.png"`

Comment: Wow, I've been trying to figure this out for a while and can't believe it was this simple. Yes, your second example worked, I hadn't realized that I can access a directory on the server without any additional syntax.